# Need help structuring database for nested navigation

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I want to create a nested navigation menu/navigation, via my database(SQLite), using PDO (in the end it should work as a dropdown menu). I've been googling around, and looked at different posts in here. But I still don't really know how to do it properly. I really need database structuring advice, and maybe an example. I know it might be a lot to ask, but I thought I'd try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a secondary sub-menu nested under the first sub-menu within a delphi in html is easy enough, you need the PDO methods and functions like:
*query_select* and *query_update*

The basic logic to code is:
make links and tables
place them in an unordered list
then insert into the "web"

A key factor for your code is whether you're designing for mobile or desktop?

For structuring examples, consider file I/O functions when performing sql query, then when the import occurs consider that the loop structure will be based on the db.
    HTH-
    CD